# How to send turtle to random position?

Tags: python, random, turtle-graphics

I have been trying to use `goto()` to send turtles to a random position but I get an error when running the program.

I am lost on how else to do this and not sure of other ways.
My current code is:

```
t1.shape('turtle')
t1.penup()
t1.goto((randint(-100,0)),(randint(100,0)))#this is the line with the error
```

I want the turtle to go to random coordinates in a box between -100,100 and 0,100 but I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\samdu_000\OneDrive\Documents\python\battle turtles.py",    line 18, in <module>

t1.goto((randint(-100,0)),(randint(100,0)))

File "C:\Users\samdu_000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python3732\lib\random.py", line 222, in randint

return self.randrange(a, b+1)

File "C:\Users\samdu_000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-
32\lib\random.py", line 200, in randrange

raise ValueError("empty range for randrange() (%d,%d, %d)" % (istart, 
istop, width))

 ValueError: empty range for randrange() (100,1, -99)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're asking for a number between 100 and 0. But look at the [reference](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html) for `randint()`:

> random.randint(a, b)
>
> Return a random integer N such that a <= N <= b.

`a` should be smaller or equal to `b`. So, replace `randint(100,0)` with `randint(0,100)`:

```
import turtle
from random import randint

t1 = turtle.Turtle()

t1.shape('turtle')
t1.penup()
t1.goto(randint(-100,0),randint(0,100))

turtle.done()
```

Demo: https://repl.it/@glhr/55439167

Comment: use setpos() in turtle

Comment: @Programmer Source? They're used interchangeably here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html#turtle.setpos

Comment: Oh my mistake @glhr

Comment: I didnt see that